# Getting started on smart signage dev

Tags: html, samsung-smart-tv

I wanted to develop a stand alone HTML5 app on Samsung Smart Signage. I am trying to find the sdk and some documentation to get started but I couldn't find any. Could anyone please point me … to the right resources to get started on Digital Signage development in HTML5? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://displaysolutions.samsung.com/aboutUs/faqList?method=list&sflag2=534&sflag3=542&sflag4=545&pageNo=1

I was unable to get to the SDK download page though, as the Samsung Logins are still notoriously bad as they have always been.